# Clear Session Variable of Page Refresh

Tags: java, html

***I think there's a better way to do this.*** If you know tell me.

My Login Page has Username, Password and a Login button. I just want to show message under the input password if login fails.

My problem is that the message stays there until I get the Login right. *If I close the page and open again te message is there.* Now I just want to clear the variable when I refresh the page so that message goes away.

HTML:

```
    <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrap-login col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">ATP Login</h2>
      <form action="Login" method="post">
        <label>Username</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
          <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <label style="margin-top: 15px;">Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
          <%
             if(session.getAttribute("loginSuccessful") != null && session.getAttribute("loginSuccessful") == "false") {
          %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <strong>Wrong username and password combination.</strong> Please, check your login information and try again.
        </div>
          <%
              }
          %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default login-btn" >Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JAVA:

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    //Check login
    Boolean successful = CheckLogin(username,password);
    if (successful) {
        response.sendRedirect("Environments.jsp");
    }
    else {
        session.setAttribute("loginSuccessful","false");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Don't put `loginSuccessful` in the `session` scope. Put it in the `request` scope, so it'll be effective only during handling the current login request.</del>

Sorry, I didn't see that you were using `sendRedirect`. In that case you'll need to clear our the session attribute on the JSP page, within the if block. Just set it to `null`.

Comment: now I get `request.getAttribute("loginSuccessful") = null` in jsp and doesn't display the message

Comment: @xasdas How are you setting it in the servlet code?

Comment: @xasdas oh never mind, I just saw that you are using `sendRedirect`. Request scope would not work in that case.